# Sqllocaldb - can db be moved to another user/machine?

Tags: sql-server

Is is possible to copy sqllocaldb database files to another user's machine and have them work?  The database owner is Default.
I can create the database on the other system but do not want to export and import the data from the original database.  Copying the file would be much easier - if it wil work.

Thanks!

Comment: `LocalDB` is just another way to using standard SQL Server `.mdf` files - so yes, you can copy those files to a SQL Server machine and attach them there to another SQL Server instance

Answer (score 1):

Try Backup - Restore, in Management Studio:

Create a .bak file `Tasks -> Backup`

and then restore on the another user's machine

`Databases -> Restore database... -> Source - Device -> Choose a file(yourbackup.bak)`

Note: check that user's machine database engine must be same(or higher) version.